# Why does the A Major chord look different in some places?

Tags: guitar, vst

I can not play the guitar but I want to use a VST plugin called Ample Guitar. Now I was looking into chords and tried to rebuild them in the ample guitar. I looked up the A Major Chord here https://gtrlib.com/chords/a-major

Then I rebuilt it in Ample Guitar Strummer Mode, but it looks different as you can see in the image; it uses 5 fingers but the figure is nowhere shown on the website.

[image]

When I put the fingers (dots) on the positions like the first position on the website it shows up as G#Maj as shown in the second image below.

[image]

So why are there different representations? I read it is a very realistic plugin so I guess I am missing something essential here.

**Edit** The strings are tuned E1 A1 D2 G2 B2 E3

Comment: Note, in the second picture, the three dots are one fret lower. So it really is G#, not A.

Comment: Right, i put all 3 dots a halftone to the right and now its A major. Thank you.

Comment: The strings are all an octave lower than on a standard guitar? Or did you just mix up the numbers?

Comment: @user93760 looks like you’re getting it but worth noting there are lots of other ways to play Amajor on a guitar too, don’t be surprised if some other unrecognisable organisation on the guitar fretboard also ends up as an Amajor!

Comment: If you don't play guitar, what are you trying to accomplish with this plugin? You found the mistake was the three dots all moved one fret lower, but what was the point if not getting the fingering to play something on guitar?

Comment: FWIW, those diagrams show a double line at the far left of the fret board for the "nut" at the end of the guitar neck. The first diagram doesn't use 5 fingers. two dots represent "open" strings (those strings are sort of 'fretted' by the nut), only the three dots in a row, on the second fret, require the fingers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note, the double vertical line in the diagram represents the nut of the guitar. The dots on the left side of the nut represent open strings, i.e. played, but not shortened by the fingers. You need to shorten only 3 string to play this A chord shape.

Comment: Thats it, thank you. I put all 3 dots 1 halftone to the right and now its an A major. My fault, i forgot the open strings because i already read about that :$ Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The chosen answer is correct. But it's a non-standard way to depict chords. True, the two dots behind the double line (nut) do represent open strings, which brings one to the conclusion that no dot means don't play that particular string. Thus, with G♯, it's only the 2nd, 3rd and 4th strings that should get played. The 'standard' way is to put 'x' on any unplayed (and unplayable) string.

Answer (score 0):

The A major chord can be played upon at least three different locations on the fretboard each having a different chord shape.  The first image is open A major using 5 strings and is usually played with three fingers (not 5) since strings 1 and 5 are open, not fretted. The image does not show what fingers to place where, only what strings to play either open or fretted. Dots to the right of the double line are fretted strings, to the left open.  The second image is a form of G# which can also be named A♭.  The open strings are not played and the three fretted note dots are one fret to the left.  You may have not realized the frets selected were at fret 1 instead of fret 2.